# List that contains the last installed / upgraded packages in Arch Linux but with skip dependences

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, logs, pacman

How can I get a list of packages, that were last installed or upgraded by `pacman`/ `pacaur` in Arch Linux including the timestamp? I have one more condition as well, I want to skip dependences. I only want the list of names, written in `pacaur -S [package]`.

**NOTE:** this question is close to this other question, titled: [List that contains the last installed / upgraded packages in Arch Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225902/list-that-contains-the-last-installed-upgraded-packages-in-arch-linux/225903#225903).

Comment: What do you have so far? Some script? You could use the answer you linked and parse the output of that command. You can filter package names with `pacman -Qe some-package`.

Comment: You would use `expac` for this.

Comment: `expac` has a formatting option that looks like what you want - https://github.com/falconindy/expac.

Comment: Btw, `pacaur` is no longer maintained. You should switch to something else.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to discover which packages were installed with `pacman -S pkgname` (or AUR helpers like pacaur), because packages which are reinstalled or updated will preserve their installation reason, and AUR helpers are responsible for specifying `--asdeps` during initial install.

However, you can use `pacman -Qqe` to get a list of explicitly installed packages, and pass that list via stdout to the `expac` command to print the dates they were last installed/updated. For example:

```
pacman -Qqe | expac -Q '%-30n\t%l' -
```

See the expac man page for more details on formatting options, particularly `--timefmt`